# Duplicate fields of a form by keeping javascript actions work

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, forms, bootstrap-4

I have built a form composed of "input text", "select option" and "checkboxes" fields.
At the bottom of my form there is a "Add a book" button. If the user clicks on that button, all the fields are duplicated beneath the form. Then the user can click on another "Add a book" button to duplicate another time all the fields beneath. And so on..
I must say that the checkboxes fields of the original form act with Javascript actions. For example, if one clicks on checkbox A, checkbox B appears.
The problem is when after clicking on the "Add a book" button, the serie of fields duplicated don't interact with Javascript controls.

I used that piece of code :

```
    <script>
    $("#Button").click(function() {
    $("#add").clone().appendTo("#wrapper");
    });
    </script>

    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
    <a class="btn btn-success" onclick="add()" href="#">
    <i class="fas fa-plus"></i></i> Add a book
    </a>
    </div>

   <div id="wrapper">
   <!-- champs du formulaire -->
   <div class="form-group col-md-12" id="add" style="display:none;">

   <!-- Cote -->    
   <div class="form-row">               
   <div class="form-group col-md-3">
   <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Côte</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cote-man" name="cote-man[]">
   </div>
   </div>
   ... And so on
```

Do you know how I could do to both duplicate my fields and make my javascript actions work too ?

Any help would be greatly appreciated !

**UPDATE** --
You can see the problem in that fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/dw25o4uq/1/
If you click on the checkbox "Texte hagiographique", another checkbox appears.
If you add another book and click on the second checkbox "Texte hagiographique", nothing appears..

Answer (score 0):

Kindly, can you provide a complete example of your code including HTML & JS

but anyway until you will provide your code complete example with the checkbox

regarding the checkbox action not fired on the new injected elements to the DOM this means that you add your checkbox event listener on the checkbox directly but in case you want an event listener on an element will be injected programmatically to the DOM tree so you just need to make some thing just like the following which called the event delegation

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  //instead of add event directly to your checkbox
  $(CHECKBOX_SELECTOR).on(EVENT_NAME, function() {
    // code will be apply on this event...
  })

  // you just need to do event delegation on the checkbox event instead of the above code you need to do it
  $(document).on(EVENT_NAME, CHECKBOX_SELECTOR, function() {
    // code will be apply on this event...
  })

})
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. See my post, I added a jsfiddle so that you could understand better what my problem is. Could you check it please ?